# If SharePoint is a good tool for a "customer portal" (general advice needed)?

Tags: document-library

I'm looking for the best solution for my needs and consider SharePont (SharePoint Foundation 2013 on-premise). Please have a look.

I'm in B2B business and results of my work are files (presentation, pdf, video etc). All files are grouped by "projects". Every project has at least name, number and date. I have not so much customers, let say, 50 and one hundred projects a month total.

What I need is that my customers could log into some web-site with nice interface, find project by name, date or number and download files from the project.

Additionally, we use in-house .Net/SQL developed software for operations. I also need to incorporate some data from SQL (like project progress in %%) to the project page.

Could you point me out if SharePoint is a good idea for this task and how to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use SharePoint for this. In fact, I did three portal-type projects in 2014.  You will need to configure FBA for external access, and you'll need to be very careful with your security implementation.

There are some third-party tools that will do some of this for you.  [Extranet Collaboration Manager](http://premierpointsolutions.com/SharePoint-Add-ons/2013-products/Pages/SharePoint-Extranet-Collaboration-Manager-2013.aspx?productKey=ExCM2013) is one that I've used and had some success (and some frustrations as well!) with.

Whether SharePoint is a good solution for your specific needs and organization is something you'll have to figure out.  You will need a talented and experienced team, because it will not be a simple or easy project.

You might also want to consider Office 365, which has the concept of [External Users](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). As long as your customers can swallow the concept of obtaining and using Live IDs for authentication, this works quite nice and has the added benefit of little or no administrative overhead/risk.